# Polymorphic Django Admin, with non-abstract inheritance

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Pretend I've got these classes:

```
# For storing arbitrary blobs
class GenericAttachment(models.Model):
    # Some fields...
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Type", choices=('Generic', 'Report', 'Image', 'Budget'))
    # Some methods...


class ReportAttachment(GenericAttachment):
    # Report specific fields
    pass

class BudgetAttachment(GenericAttachment):
    # Budget-specific fields
    pass

class Record(models.Model):
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField(GenericAttachment, blank=True, null=True)

class DataEntry(models.Model):
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField(GenericAttachment, blank=True, null=True)
```

The real ones are slightly more complicated, but not much.

When the type of A is 'Report' I want to use the Report class for the extra fields, and the same with Budget. None of the other types have their own unique fields and so don't need their own subclasses, however. I'd also like to avoid having 3 ManyToMany fields per Record/DataEntry... a list of all the attachments is preferable, but it should open the correct create/edit form depending on the actual type.

Ideally, I'd like an interface that added and removed the Report and Budget specific fields when the user changes the type, and saves as the correct type. I could write my own view to do it, but the rest of the little app is done with the admin interface and I was hoping to keep the whole thing that way. So... can anyone think of a good way to get this behaviour in the admin interface?

Comment: Alternatively, if I need to, I'd settle for a nice way to split out the types on the admin. I guess there would be one field for Attachments that did _not_ include those of type Budget and Report, and another fields for each of those that only had those types.

Comment: Since we're dealing with a relational database, it seems like what you're looking for instead is a `Proxy model` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models. Inserting / removing rows from one table to another doesn't seem like a nice solution.